# HTML and JavaScript Code Review

Tags: javascript, html, function

**Please** Have a Look at my code i am not getting results when function total_Cost(); is called i am not understanding why this is happening to me.

```js
function total_Cost()
{
    var x = document.getElemenById('1');
    var y = document.getElemenById('2');
    var z = document.getElemenById('3');
    var s = document.getElemenById('cost');
    s.value = (x.value * 3.49) + (y.value * 3.60) + (z.value * 4.49);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>Coffee Order Form</h2>
    <form method='get'>
        <table border="1" cellpadding='0px' cellspacing='0px'>
            <tr><th>Product Name </th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
            <tr><td>French Vanilla (1 lb)</td><td>$3.49</td><td><input type = "text" size='5'id='1' value=''></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Hazelnut Cream (1 lb)</td><td>$3.60</td><td><input type = "text" size='5'id='2' value=''></td></tr>
            <tr><td align='centre'>Colombian (1 lb)</td><td>$4.49</td><td><input type = "text" size='5' id='3' value=''></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type='button' Value='Total Cost' id='total' onclick='return total_Cost();'> &nbsp;<input type = "text" size='10' id='cost' value=''>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' Value='Submit Order'> &nbsp; <input type='submit' Value='Clear Order Form'>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: actually, its just badly worded, its not for code review, he has a problem

Comment: He has a problem. I think it's just an unfortunate title.

Comment: exactly i am not understating where is problem

Comment: you have multiple problems

Comment: please explain today i have to submit that assignment's solution :(

Comment: `getElemenById`.  What's an "Elemen"?  :-P  That should be `getElementById`!

Comment: hahahah opps yes you are right :P

Comment: O Yeah Problem Fixes Thankssss Rocket Hazmat :) and all who viewed and replied :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    function total_Cost()
    {
        var x=document.getElementById('1');
        var y=document.getElementById('2');
        var z=document.getElementById('3');
        var s=document.getElementById('cost');
        s.value=(x.value * 3.49) +(y.value * 3.60) + (z.value * 4.49);
    }
</script>
```

You forgot the t in Element.

Comment: Thank You Kolby Function is executed know :)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue, apart from a number of spelling mistakes, is you don't need to return from your onclick function.

However, I would suggest you use event listeners in this case to avoid confusion.

```js
function total_Cost() {
    var x = document.getElementById('1');
    var y = document.getElementById('2');
    var z = document.getElementById('3');
    var s = document.getElementById('cost');
    s.value = (x.value * 3.49) + (y.value * 3.60) + (z.value * 4.49);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>Coffee Order Form</h2>
    <form method='get'>
        <table border="1" cellpadding='0px' cellspacing='0px'>
            <tr><th>Product Name </th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
            <tr><td>French Vanilla (1 lb)</td><td>$3.49</td><td><input type = "text" size='5'id='1' value=''></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Hazelnut Cream (1 lb)</td><td>$3.60</td><td><input type = "text" size='5'id='2' value=''></td></tr>
            <tr><td align='centre'>Colombian (1 lb)</td><td>$4.49</td><td><input type = "text" size='5' id='3' value=''></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type='button' Value='Total Cost' id='total' onclick='total_Cost();'> &nbsp;<input type = "text" size='10' id='cost' value=''>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' Value='Submit Order'> &nbsp; <input type='submit' Value='Clear Order Form'>
    </form>
</body>
```